# NPE after migrating jsf 1.2 to 2.0 - viewId=null

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, jboss6.x, myfaces

I upgraded jboss eap 6.4 with jsf 1.2 + richfaces 3.3.3 + jsp view to jsf 2 + richfaces3.3.3Final with jsf2-impl and chose to stay with jsp view for now.
I disabled facelets in web.xml using:

```
  <context-param>
         <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

I also changed faces-config so it will use jsf 2 version.
I checked my class path and did not see any trace of old jsf 1.2 jars.
Server starts up without errors, but I am getting the following NP exception when I try to load pages, it looks like UIViewRoot viewId is null. any idea what might cause this?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager

viewId=null
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at 
org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.
JspTilesTwoViewHandlerImpl.deriveVieId(JspTilesTwoViewHandlerImpl.java:250)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager
at      org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.
Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.
initManager(Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:136)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesTwoViewHandlerImpl.deriveViewId(JspTilesTwoViewHandlerImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesTwoViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspTilesTwoViewHandlerImpl.java:114)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.traiana.platform.core.beans.FacesInstanceManagerFilter.doFilter(FacesInstanceManagerFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.securityfilter.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:212)
    at com.traiana.platform.web.security.SessionTrackingFilter.doFilter(SessionTrackingFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.traiana.platform.web.security.ChangePasswordFilter.doFilter(ChangePasswordFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.securityfilter.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:212)
    at com.traiana.platform.web.security.TraianaSecurityFilter.doFilter(TraianaSecurityFilter.java:136)
    at com.traiana.solcommon.web.security.CommonSecurityFilter.doFilter(CommonSecurityFilter.java:161)
```

Class Path:

```
  [echo] Classpath = D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\IC-1.2.22.4.6.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\Ic-Integration-1.0.0.0.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\Venus-1.0.9.0.18.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\an
r-3.4-complete.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\avalon-framework-cvs-20020806.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\batik-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\collections-generic-4.01.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\
b\com.ibm.mq-6.0.2.6.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\com.ibm.mqjms-6.0.2.6.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.2.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP
NF\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-dbcp-1.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-digester-1.5.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-discovery-0.4.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platfor
ar\APP-INF\lib\commons-el-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\A
-INF\lib\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\commons-pool-1.4.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\AP
INF\lib\commons-validator-1.1.3-dev.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.2.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\cryptix-jce-provider.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\cryptix-openpgp-provider.ja
D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\cryptix.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\db-ojb-1.0.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\dhbcore-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\esapi-2.1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF
ib\fop-0.20.5.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\guava-18.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\javassist-3.18.0-GA.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\jcommon-0.9.6
ar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\jdom-1.1.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\jdom2-2.0.5.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\jfreechart-0.9.21.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\joda-time-2.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platfo
Ear\APP-INF\lib\json-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\junit-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\jxl-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\ldapjdk-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;D:\a
h\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\myfaces-api-2.0.23.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\myfaces-impl-2.0.23.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\opencsv-2.3.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\opensaml-2.6.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\plat
rmEar\APP-INF\lib\openws-1.5.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\pluto-1.2.2.9.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\quartz-2.1.3.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\quartz-oracle-2.1.3.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\
b\reflections-0.9.9-RC1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar;D:\ar
\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\securityfilter-2.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM
latformEar\APP-INF\lib\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\stax2-api-3.1.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\tiles-api-2.0.7.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\tiles-core-2.0.7.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\A
-INF\lib\tiles-jsp-2.0.7.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\tsik-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\velocity-1.5.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\vtd-xml-1.0
ar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\woodstox-core-asl-4.1.2.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\xml_prod_key-1
.jar;D:\arch\TRM\platformEar\APP-INF\lib\xmltooling-1.3.1.jar;D:\arch\TRM\db\dev\bin\createDB-1.0.jar;D:\jdk1.8.0_40\lib\tools.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\archant.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-antlr.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib
nt-apache-bcel.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-apache-bsf.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-apache-log4j.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-apache-oro.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-apache-regexp.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\
b\ant-apache-resolver.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-apache-xalan2.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-commons-logging.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-commons-net.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar;d:\apache-
t\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-jai.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-javamail.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-jdepend.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-jmf.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-jsch.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-junit.
r;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-junit4.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-launcher.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-netrexx.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-swing.jar;d:\apache
nt\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant-testutil.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\ant.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\lib\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\truezip-6.jar;d:\apache-ant\1.9.5\ant\xmltask.jar;D:\arch\TRM\lib\auto-value-1.0-rc1.jar
:\arch\TRM\lib\fincad\fincad-1.0.jar;D:\arch\TRM\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;D:\arch\TRM\lib\starteam\starteam-sdk-1.0.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\activation\api\main\activation-1.1.1.redhat-4.jar;D:\Java\jboss-e
-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\annotation\api\main\jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\ejb\api\main\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Jav
jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\el\api\main\jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-1.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\enterprise\api\main\cdi-api-1.0.0.SP4-redhat-5.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\mo
les\system\layers\base\javax\enterprise\deploy\api\main\jboss-jad-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\faces\api\main\jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar;D:\Java\jboss
ap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\inject\api\main\javax.inject-1.0.0.redhat-5.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\interceptor\api\main\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-e
-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\jms\api\main\jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\jws\api\main\jsr181-api-1.0.0.MR1-redhat-7.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\syste
layers\base\javax\mail\api\main\mail-1.4.5.redhat-2.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\management\j2ee\api\main\jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\bas
javax\persistence\api\main\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\resource\api\main\jboss-connector-api_1.6_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\syste
layers\base\javax\rmi\api\main\jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\security\auth\message\api\main\jboss-jaspi-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4
odules\system\layers\base\javax\security\jacc\api\main\jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec-1.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\servlet\api\main\jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar;D:\Java\
oss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\servlet\jsp\api\main\jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\servlet\jstl\api\main\jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.0.6.Final-redhat-1.
r;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\transaction\api\main\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\validation\api\main\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-red
t-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\ws\rs\api\main\jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\wsdl4j\api\main\wsdl4j-1.6.3.redhat-1.jar;D:\Java\jbo
-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\xml\bind\api\main\jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\xml\registry\api\main\jboss-jaxr-api_1.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-3.jar;D
Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\xml\rpc\api\main\jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-4.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\xml\soap\api\main\jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec-1.0.3.Final-redhat-
jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\javax\xml\ws\api\main\jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\infinispan\main\infinispan-core-5.2.11.Final-redhat-2.jar;
\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\log4j\logmanager\main\log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logmanager\main\jboss-logmanager-1.5.4.Final-redha
1.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-4.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar;D:\Java\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-commons-1.0.0.final-redhat-3.jar;D:\Java\jboss-ea
6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-infinispan-4.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar
```

Comment: Problem is in MyFaces Tomahawk. Are you sure you're using Tomahawk for JSF 2.x and not for JSF 1.x?

Comment: Yes, I had Tomahawk12 1.1.8, and upgraded it to Tomahawk20 1.1.14.  I added my class path above.

Comment: I found another exception in the log: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/InstanceManager   at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.initManager(Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:136)
 at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.postConstruct(Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider.java:85) It does not look as if I am missing some dependency, any idea ???

Comment: No, it indeed looks like you've too much dependencies. To be precisely, you seem to have server-specific libraries of an older Tomcat version embedded in webapp itself. Something like `servlet-api.jar`, `catalina.jar`, etc. Those files which you already see in Tomcat's own `/lib` folder. Get rid of them all in webapp. Server-specific libraries don't belong in webapp. The server provides them all by itself.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC but I cant seem to find the conflict. I am using jboss eap 6.4 the catalina jars are comming from it's modules. I thought maybe  \base\org\jboss\as\jsf -> jboss-as-jsf-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar does not support jsf 2?